# Какой формат url адреса использовать лучше для seo?

Tags: seo

Есть вариант ссылок на пост:

1. site.ru/310-biznes-zakladki
2. site.ru/310-biznes-zakladki.html
3. site.ru/310_biznes_zakladki
4. site.ru/310_biznes_zakladki.html

Какой вариант наилучший с точки зрения seo и почему?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Очевидно
В 2 и 4 варианте ты указываешь расширения фаила индекса, это лишнее и не надо. В 3 варианте нижнее подчеркивание роботами воспринимается как нижнее подчеркивание. В первом же, оно может быть воспринято роботом как пробел между словами

Comment: Спасибо! Значит 1 вариант самый лучший? Нужно ли добавить в конце закрывающий слеш site.ru/310-biznes-zakladki/   ?

Answer (score 1):

Может моя информация не актуальна и для различных поисковиков (алгоритмов) различна, но - файл "в корне" (2,4) сайта может иметь больший вес нежели файлы в подпапках. Ну и в давние времена некие "динамические" страницы пытались маскировать под статические в том числе расширением ".html" (конечно до кучи подделывались заголовки).

**А теперь главное** - советую проанализировать топ 10-20-100 в Я/G по интересующим запросам и посмотреть какие конструкции URL в топе.

Comment: Спасибо! А что значит "подделывались заголовки", это как?

Comment: @MicroRu помню Last-Modified:, может еще что (например всякие *-cache)

Comment: @MicroRu ну то есть у динамики  Last-Modified он же "сейчас", а у статики когда файл записан на сервер и не меняется. На определенных алгоритмах поставив дату давнюю можно было сканать за "первоисточник" таковым не являясь. Но опыт старый, отошел я от темы

Comment: @MicroRu сейчас думаю ИИ (ML) под каждый запрос свои веса пытается расставить и тогда черт его знает как карта лежит, надо анализировать серп по конкретному запросу.

Comment: Хорошо, буду тестировать, спасибо.